# Appium 1.5.2 cannot perform SWIPE, always gives the error "point is not within the bounds of the screen", but works very well with Appium 1.4.8

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

Appium 1.5.2 cannot perform SWIPE, always gives the error "point is not within the bounds of the screen", but the same command works very well with Appium 1.4.13

Environment:

APPIUM 1.5.2
iOS 9.2.1
MAC OS

Any idea how to solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Swipe method Criteria(Only for IOS) to avoid this error**

1. startx + endx < width
2. starty + endy < Height

Issue is endx and endy input parameters of the driver.swipe method is implemented differently for IOS.It is actually deltaX and deltaY for IOS.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38480848/1802348) answer for solution and detailed RCA of issue.