# Cannot swipe from bottom to top on ios - appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I would like to set the wifi status on ios and in order to do that, I need to to swipe up from the bottom the Control Center.

```
    dimension = driverWrapper.getIosDriver().manage().window().getSize();
    int middleX = dimension.getWidth() / 2;
    int y = dimension.getHeight();
   driverWrapper.getIosDriver().swipe(middleX,y-10,middleX,150,600);
```

Before I upgraded java client to 4.0.0 and appium to 1.5.2 it worked correctly.

I get an error of:
**Error: VerboseError: point is not within the bounds of the screen**

The logs are:

```
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (49 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"width":320,"height":568}}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getWindowSize() result: {"width":320,"height":568}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/31411e39-f408-418f-b9b8-e28b80ba1b35/window/current/size 200 1071 ms - 98 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/31411e39-f408-418f-b9b8-e28b80ba1b35/touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"x":160,"y":558}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":100}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":160,"y":284}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"press","options":{"x":160,"y":558}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":100}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":160,"y":284}},{"action":"...
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'performTouch'
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: target.touch([{"touch":[{"x":160,"y":558}],"time":0.2},{"touch":[{"x":160,"y":558}],"time":0.30000000000000004},{"touch":[{"x":320,"y":842}],"time":0.5}])

[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-06-19 07:39:13 +0000 Debug: Got new command 6 from instruments: target.touch([{"touch":[{"x":160,"y":558}],"time":0.2},{"touch":[{"x":160,"y":558}],"time":0.30000000000000004},{"touch":[{"x":320,"y":842}],"time":0.5}])

[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-06-19 07:39:13 +0000 Debug: evaluating target.touch([{"touch":[{"x":160,"y":558}],"time":0.2},{"touch":[{"x":160,"y":558}],"time":0.30000000000000004},{"touch":[{"x":320,"y":842}],"time":0.5}])

[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-06-19 07:39:13 +0000 Debug: target.touch(__NSCFArray)

[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-06-19 07:39:13 +0000 Debug: point is not within the bounds of the screen
```

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with something lie y-30 as startY ?

Comment: yes. never worked.

Comment: i also tried:              action = new TouchAction(driverWrapper.getIosDriver());
            action.press(middleX, y - 1 ).waitAction(1000)
                    .moveTo(middleX, y / 2).release().perform();

Comment: swipe method itself using TouchAction! so it would obviously not work! check source code!

Answer (score 2):

**Swipe method Criteria(Only for IOS) to avoid this error**

1. 0 < startx + endx < width
2. 0 < starty + endy < Height

**Pragmatic permanent solution**

For to simplify our day to day life, write down a function like this

```
public void swipeFinger(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration) {
   driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx - endx, starty - endy, duration);
}
```

**RCA for Error: VerboseError: point is not within the bounds of the screen**

Issue is endx and endy input parameters of the driver.swipe method is implemented differently for IOS.

It is actually deltaX and deltaY for IOS.Look at this image and Consider your finger is at the origin(intersection of both axis).

[image]

If you want to swipe your finger down or Right side you need to pass positive endx and endy positive value and if you want to swipe down to up or right to left you need to pass negative value of pixels you want to swipe your finger.

**20 pixel Right Swipe**

driver.swipe(startx, starty, 20, 0, duration)

because you do not want to move your finger in vertical direction so y is always zero!

**20 pixel Down Swipe**

driver.swipe(startx, starty, 0, 20, duration)

because you do not want to move your finger in Horizontal direction so x is always zero!

Now UP and Left swipe actions

**20 pixel UP Swipe Action**

driver.swipe(startx, starty, 0, -20, duration)

**20 pixel Left Swipe Action**

driver.swipe(startx, starty, -20, 0, duration)

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = driver;

executor.executeScript(
    "target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.1}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.7}, duration:0.8});");
```

Check if this works .. if not try to reduce the y:0.01 further.

Comment: thank you very much for your help but it's still not working.
i think there is a progress because now i don't get the error: point is not within the bounds of the screen.
what happens now is that the swipe is ignored. It is not performed.

Comment: Swipe method Criteria(Only for IOS) to avoid this error

1. startx + endx < width
2. starty + endy < Height

Answer (score 0):

Python version for iOS10 with Appium 1.6.5:

```
def swipe_up(self):

logging.info("swipe up")
sleep(1)
window_size = self.driver.get_window_size()  # this returns dictionary
sleep(1)
el = self.driver.find_element(*self.configuration.CommonScreen.WEB_VIEW)
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
sleep(1)
start_x = window_size["width"] * 0.5
start_y = window_size["height"]
end_x = window_size["width"] * 0.5
end_y = window_size["height"] * 0.5
action.press(el, start_x, start_y).wait(100).move_to(el, end_x, end_y).release().perform()
sleep(1)
```

For iOS9 You need to change wait to 1000.